# How can I add structured data to one page containing event and reviews of event?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have a HTML page that displays an event. Together with the event there are reviews and an aggregated rating.

Now I want to add structured data with schema.org to be extracted by search engines.

The item type http://schema.org/Event does not support the properties "aggregateRating" or "review".

I tried to put different item scopes next to each other. I have linked them by using the "itemReviewed" property as a link to an "itemid":

```
<div itemid="#myevent" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemscope>

    ....

    <dl itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
      <link href="#myevent" itemprop="itemReviewed">
      <meta content="4.5" itemprop="ratingValue">
      <meta content="6" itemprop="reviewCount">
      ...
    </dl>

    <dl itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope>
      <link href="#myevent" itemprop="itemReviewed">
      <p itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope 
         itemprop="reviewRating">Rating: <img src="...">
         <meta content="4" itemprop="ratingValue">
       </p>
      ...
    </dl>

</div>
```

[Google Rich Snippet Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) does not complain. But in the preview it only displays one of the review items. No display of event date or location. No display of aggregate review.

I don't know if this is just a problem of Snippet Tool or if real Google Search extracts the same.

Could you please tell me how I could improve my markup?

Is the usage of itemid / link correct?

Is there any schema that has startdate, enddate and aggregateRating and reviews?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problem. The best solution I found was to use Microformats.
So you calculate the average rating for the event (rating you want to show on Google's rich snippet) and do this:

```
<div itemid="#myevent" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemscope class="hreview-aggregate">

    <h1 class="fn" itemprop="name">Event</h1>

    <div>
        Rated <span class="rating">3.5</span>/5 based on <span class="count">11</span> reviews
    </div>

    <dl itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
      <link href="#myevent" itemprop="itemReviewed">
      ...

</div>
```

That should do the trick. The only problem is that then you get Warning
`Warning: If count is specified in review aggregate, page should contain reviews. Otherwise you may want to use votes. More information about aggregate reviews.`